# Rewriting (hiding) jsp extension brakes servlets

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-jk

I'm trying to remove/hide .jsp extensions in my URLs with the following rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.jsp [PT,L]
```

It works for jsp fine but brakes my servlets that I use with Ajax in my jsp forms - they do not work anymore.

My jk rules:

```
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
JkMount /* ajp13
JkMount /b/* ajp13
JkUnMount /*.php* ajp13
JkUnMount /*.pl ajp13
JkUnMount /*.cgi ajp13
JkUnMount /*.html ajp13
JkUnMount /*.htm ajp13
JkUnMount /*.shtm* ajp13
JkUnMount /*.gif ajp13
JkUnMount /*.jpeg ajp13
JkUnMount /*.png ajp13
JkUnMount /*.css ajp13
JkUnMount /*.js ajp13
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas on how to separate jsp and servlets in the rule above? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding q particular URI works

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myServlet$
```